# How to subtract two Maps in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have two Maps Collection with pairs ,say,
Consider Values as List Of Integers.
ie, for Map1,key=1,values =array list with (2,3)

```
Map1       Map2
<1,2>      <1,2>
<1,3>      <1,4>
<2,4>      <2,5>
<2,5>      <2,6>
```

Now i want results as Map1-Map2 :

```
<1,3>
<2,5>
```

or Map2-Map1:

```
<1,4>
<2,6>
```

Is there a similar method like RemoveAll in ArrayLists for Maps ? Also, which Map(SortedMap?) would be the best way to achieve this ?

I'm a beginner If you could guide me in right direction than down voting , it would be great .

Comment: First and foremost, a map can't have 2 entries with the same key.

Comment: .entrySet().removeAll()?

Comment: @R.J If i have List Of Values ,as pairs , i meant ?

Comment: A map cannot have duplicate keys. Otherwise, you can loop over entries of Map1 and remove the entries from Map2 one by one. If you want to compare values also put that in an if condition

Answer (score 0):

This is in the Guava library provided by google.  There's a method called `entriesOnlyOnLeft()` that allows you to provide two maps and show the unique entries from the map on the left of the query.  Link to the library [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Maps)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must learn about `Map` in `Java`. You can't have duplicate `keys`. If you put new `entry` with same key, previous value will replace. Key must be unique.

So your question is not valid.

```
 Map1       Map2
<1,2>      <1,2>
<1,3>      <1,4>
<2,4>      <2,5>
<2,5>      <2,6>
```

Consider your case, final map will be follows. previous value for same key will replace by new value.

```
 Map1       Map2
 <1,3>     <1,4>
 <2,5>     <2,6>
```

You can do something like following

```
    Map<Integer,Integer> map1=new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer,Integer> map2=new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1,2);
    map1.put(2,3);
    map1.put(3,4);

    map2.put(1,2);
    map2.put(2,2);
    map2.put(3,2);

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry:map2.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue().equals(map1.get(entry.getKey()))){
            map1.remove(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map1);
```

Comment: I said if i have List of Values for a key. What about that case?

Comment: @David then Iterate through map and remove common element with respect to your reference map.

Comment: So for each key in Map1 , i can use ArrayListForKeyInMap1.RemoveAll(ArrayListForKeyInMap2) in value lists ?

Comment: @Ruchira: you should *never* compare `Integer` instances using `==`. It might work in some cases, especially with small values, but it might break in other. But I don’t get the purpose of your loop anyway. Why don’t you use `map1.entrySet().removeAll(map2.entrySet())`?

Answer (score 0):

Now that it is clear that you want to have a `Set` of pairs, the solution is rather easy. First you have to decide what pair class you want to use, e.g. `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` or a custom written. In case of a custom `Pair` class you must ensure to have proper `equals`and `hashCode` method implementations. But the advantage of a custom `Pair` class is that you can provide a `toString` method returning the proper pair representation while the `Entry` implementation has an improper `String` representation when using as pair. Therefore in my example I added a custom `Set` to `String` conversion method.

→ Using `Set`s you can simply use `removeAll` as you asked:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
  Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> set1=new HashSet<>(), set2=new HashSet<>();
  put(set1, 1, 2);
  put(set1, 1, 3);
  put(set1, 2, 4);
  put(set1, 2, 5);

  put(set2, 1, 2);
  put(set2, 1, 4);
  put(set2, 2, 5);
  put(set2, 2, 6);

  System.out.println("Set1: "+printAsTuple(set1));
  System.out.println("Set2: "+printAsTuple(set2));
  Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> uniqueSet1=new HashSet<>(set1);
  uniqueSet1.removeAll(set2);
  System.out.println("Unique in Set1: "+printAsTuple(uniqueSet1));
  Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> uniqueSet2=new HashSet<>(set2);
  uniqueSet2.removeAll(set1);
  System.out.println("Unique in Set2: "+printAsTuple(uniqueSet2));
}

private static <A,B> void put(Set<Map.Entry<A,B>> set1, A a, B b)
{
  set1.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(a, b));
}

private static String printAsTuple(Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> set)
{
  if(set.isEmpty()) return "[]";
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder().append("[ ");
  for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e:set)
    sb.append('<').append(e.getKey()).append(",").append(e.getValue()).append(">, ");
  sb.setLength(sb.length()-2);
  return sb.append(" ]").toString();
}
```